# Matplotlib fails to install on Mac OS 10.8.2 using Python 2.7.3

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, installation, osx-lion

I've installed numpy and when I go to install Matplotlib it fails. Regardless of the method I use to install it. Below are the errors I receive.

```
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -    
DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -  
I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/local/include -
I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -
I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_png.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/_png.o

src/_png.cpp:23:20: error: png.h: No such file or directory

src/_png.cpp:66: error: variable or field ‘write_png_data’ declared void

src/_png.cpp:66: error: ‘png_structp’ was not declared in this scope

src/_png.cpp:66: error: ‘png_bytep’ was not declared in this scope

src/_png.cpp:66: error: ‘png_size_t’ was not declared in this scope

src/_png.cpp:23:20: error: png.h: No such file or directory

src/_png.cpp:66: error: variable or field ‘write_png_data’ declared void

src/_png.cpp:66: error: ‘png_structp’ was not declared in this scope

src/_png.cpp:66: error: ‘png_bytep’ was not declared in this scope

src/_png.cpp:66: error: ‘png_size_t’ was not declared in this scope

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:   
/var/folders/c9/xzv35t2n3ld9lgjrtl0vd0xr0000gn/T//ccwRj4ny.out

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -
c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/c9/xzv35t2n3ld9lgjrtl0vd0xr0000gn/T/pip-
build/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/c9/xzv35t2n3ld9lgjrtl0vd0xr0000gn/T/pip-
udXluz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error
code 1 in /var/folders/c9/xzv35t2n3ld9lgjrtl0vd0xr0000gn/T/pip-build/matplotlib
Storing complete log
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have libpng. Depending on the backgrounds you choose, you are also likely to find other compiling problems. If you want to compile from source, you should understand what are the requirements and install them. I'd generally avoid compiling from source, especially for OSX when so many other options are available.

Comment: I recommend installing [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda) which comes with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

The file `png.h` is installed with [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), which is a requirement for building [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#biuld-requirements).

Please note that the later versions of libpng (1.5, and 1.6 are quite different and that the requirement specification of 1.2 or higher might not work out for you because of incompatibilities. I have succesfully been using libpng 1.2 with matplotlib but have not tried the latest 1.6 series.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install Python on a Mac is to use the one-click installer `Enthought Python Distribution` and avoid compile time dependencies. It has a 32-bit free version available for Mac OS X [0]. `Matplotlib` and `libpng`(which seems to be your dependency) are included in the free version [1].

[0] http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php

[1] http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php